# how to move the selected item in a list box into a text box?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to move the selected item of a select tag (list box) into a text box after clicking a button. i am using the below code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function copy()
            {
                var sel = document.getElementById('lb').value;
                document.getElementById('FileName').value = sel;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="frm1" id="frm1">
            <select id="lb" name="lb" size="5">
                    <option value="abc.txt">abc.txt</option>
                    <option value="def.txt">def.txt</option>
            </select>

            <input type="button" value=">>" name="btn_move" id="btn_move" onclick="copy()">

            <input type="text" name="FileName" id="FileName">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the above code works properly in google chrome browser but it does not work when i run the page in IE. can anyone tell me whats the problem in the code and kindly suggest a javascript or any other code which is compatible ith both google chrome and IE.

above code works after i allow the pop up that comes but
actually the below code is not working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FILE</title>
        <style>
            body{background-color:#b0c4de;}
            #OutBound{text-align:center;}
            #btn_sbmt{position:absolute;top:150px;left:700px;}
            #div_text_label{position:absolute;top:50px;left:200px;}
            #lbl2{position:absolute;top:80px;left:200px;}
            #selected_list{position:absolute;width:300px;top:80px;left:335px;}
            #btn_move{position:absolute;top:100px;left:650px;}
            #FileName{position:absolute;width:300px;top:100px;left:700px;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function load_list()
            {
                document.getElementById('div_main_select').style.display="none";
                var textbox = document.getElementById('pattern');
                var listbox = document.getElementById('selected_list');
                var mainListbox = document.getElementById('lb');
                listbox.innerHTML = '';
                for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < mainListbox.children.length; childIndex++)
                {
                    var child = mainListbox.children[childIndex];
                    option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.innerHTML = child.innerHTML;
                    listbox.appendChild(option);
                }
                alert (load_list_1);
            }
            function get_list()
            {
                var textbox = document.getElementById('pattern');
                var listbox = document.getElementById('selected_list');
                var mainListbox = document.getElementById('lb');
                listbox.innerHTML = '';
                for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < mainListbox.children.length; childIndex++)
                {
                    var child = mainListbox.children[childIndex];
                    if (child.innerHTML.search(textbox.value) != -1)
                    {
                        option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.innerHTML = child.innerHTML;
                        listbox.appendChild(option);
                    }
                }
                alert (get_list_1);
            }
            function copy()
            {
                var sel = document.getElementById('selected_list').value;
                document.getElementById('FileName').value = sel;
                alert (copy_1);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="color: black; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: url(background-1204x927.jpg);" BGCOLOR="#ffffff" text="black" link="#B03060" vlink="#B03060" onload="load_list()">
        <hr>
        <form id="OutBound" name="OutBound" action="" method="GET">
            <div style="text-align:center;" id="div_text_label" name="div_text_label">
                <label id="lbl1" name="lbl1">search :</label>
                <input type="text" name="pattern" id="pattern" onKeyUp="get_list()">
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;" id="div_main_select" name="div_main_select">
                <select id="lb" name="lb" size="5">
                    <option value="abc.txt">abc.txt</option>
                    <option value="def.txt">def.txt</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label id="lbl2" name="lbl2">File List:</label>
            <select id="selected_list" name="selected_list" size="5">
            </select><br>
            <input type="button" value=">>" name="btn_move" id="btn_move" onclick="copy()">
            <input type="text" name="FileName" id="FileName">
            <input type="submit" name="btn_sbmt" id="btn_sbmt" value="MOVE FILES">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

the page works like this.. 
1) there is a list box (lb) populated with some items. 
2) there is 1 more empty list box (selected_list).
3) when the page form is loaded load_list() function is called which loads the empty list   box (selected_list) with the contents of the original list box (lb). 
4) when someone enters a word or a letter in the search text box then get_list() function is called which filters the files according to the words entered.
5) when a filename is selected in the selected_list and >> button is pressed, the copy() function is called and the filename is copied to the FILENAME text box.

but this all is not working in IE but it works in google chrome. can anyone fix the code so that it works with IE also.

Comment: did you allow the script access pop up that comes up at the bottom of the page? Once you do it works fine.

Comment: at the bottom or at the top, depending on the IE version

Comment: I am try this code in IE and this is properly work. you chagne your IE version and check again.

Comment: which IE version it is not working in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function copy() {
    var sel = document.getElementById('lb');
    document.getElementById('FileName').value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLgck/) in IE)

If you are opening the file from local file system, the IE may ask your permission to run script. You should click `"Allow Blocked Content"` for it to work

See image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (1.10.1)

```
  function copy()
        {
            $("#FileName").val($("#lb").val());
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Axu8/

**Update** 
http://jsbin.com/onayow/1

Comment: after allowing the pop up it works fine.. but my actual script is below.. this is not working in IE. neither of the javascripts are working i guess.